# How to start firefox without any menu-, tool-, scroll- or whatever-bars, but not in fullscreen mode?

Tags: firefox

[AutoHide](http://www.krickelkrackel.de/autohide/autohidehelp.htm) (when using '-fullscreen' command line parameter) almost does this (except of the scrollbar), but I want it in normal mode.

It is needed because of screen is split with other programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using of [HideMenubar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4762) and prepared profile with disabled toolbar, statusbar, menubar and navbar helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust this in about:config I believe
go to about:config in firefox
filter: Dom
You should be able to disable specific parts of the browser

Comment: Nothing useful found there: http://vi-server.org/vi/tmp/q.png

Comment: @Vi look at the DOM.Disable keys.

Comment: Have just tried settigns dom.disable_window_open_feature.* values both all to "true" and all to "false" without any visible effect (restarted Firefox each time)